# How to Confirm user group permissions in the current fuse user group

Tags: mount, permissions, filesystem

I have created a folder "mtp" in /Media and its  /media/mtp.
The basic property tells: Type:- Folder(inode/directory) and in Permissions it shows Owner and Group as root. It says you are not the owner, so you cannot change these permissions.

How can i Change the permissions. **How to Confirm user group permissions in the current fuse user group**

Comment: Are you looking to mount xiaomi device on your ubuntu ?